# Local require() paths for React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am looking for a convenient way to access files in the root of my application while avoiding require() strings that look like:

```
require('../../../../myModule')
```

There are some good solutions out there for Node (https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520) but I haven't seen a way to use global variables in React Native.

Does anyone have a clean solution to this problem?

Comment: I'd suggest reading the comments on that gist. The fact that you're doing this kind of thing often indicates a smell in your code structure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From Marc Shilling's answer on https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3099

> You can use an absolute path on imports/requires:
>
> `import {ProximaNovaText} from 'MyApp/src/components';
>   require('MyApp/src/utils/moment-twitter');`
>
> where 'MyApp' is whatever name you registered in your index.ios.js file

Note for VS Code: This works, but be warned that you might lose intellisense and cmd/ctrl + click. Thanks Johan for the info about CS code

Comment: Could you give some more information, such as version of React Native, how to reproduce your bug, etc.; or create a small github repo that reproduces the bug ?

Comment: Latest version. I would, but I already put much time to report lot's of bugs in React Native, many of which were simply closed and forwarded to product pains where they wait to die alone.

Comment: This works, but be warned that you might lose intellisense and `cmd/ctrl + click` (in VSCode anyway).

Answer (score 10):

You can mark a directory as a package by adding a `package.json` within the root directory you want to resolve.

e.g:

```
- app
    - package.json     // ← Add this package.json file
    - config
    - components
    - ... (etc)
```

`package.json` should look like this:

```
{ "name": "app" }
```

> **Restart your packager**
>
> ```
> react-native start --reset-cache
> ```

Now you can use the following in all of you project files:

```
import store from 'app/config/store';
import Button from 'app/components/Button';
```

You can use this same method across other directories in your project, I don't think this works via `require`, although image paths seemed work.

---

As noted in the comments, you may lose auto-complete in your editor (VSCode).

For Jetbrains IDE's there are some ongoing tickets here:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17254
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20104#comment=27-1486526
- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205434510-Configure-custom-modules-resolve-folder

This might help with Jetbrains IDE's in the meantime.

```
// A slash may allow auto-complete to work in your IDE (but will fail to resolve)
import Button from '/app/components/Button'; // Cannot be resolved
```

Comment: This works, but be warned that you might lose intellisense and `cmd/ctrl + click` (in VSCode anyway).

Answer (score 6):

Put code below on top of your `myModule` file:

```
/**
 * @providesModule myModule
 */
```

Then you can use `require('myModule')` in any other files.

Comment: OP should have mentioned this uses Facebook's internal API and it could change or be discontinued at any time. See https://github.com/facebook/fbjs

Comment: Hi  my code /**
 * @providesModule react-native-implementation
 * flow
 */ few day before it was working but 
I install in new system it is not working, what's going wrong please help

Answer (score 4):

Complementing @Tiagojdferreira

You can use his solution with babel-plugin-module-resolver library.

Install with:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

Configure .babelrc adding plugins property like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "alias": {
        "@src": "MyApp/src",
        "@otherAlias": "MyApp/src/other/path",
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Usage:

```
require('@src/utils/moment-twitter');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a great approach with annotation approach in babel

Answer (score 0):

You can use global variables in react native, same as node, properties defined on global are accessible globally.

e.g.

```
global.foo = "blah";
console.log(foo); //logs "blah"
```

Most of the node solutions in the gist above should work correctly.

One I've used in the past is defining  a global function at the top directory level, usually on the first line like

```
global.rootRequire = function(path) { return require(path); }
```

Which simply allows deeply nested  requires to be from the root, and avoids all of the `../../` business.

However the other comment is true, if this is really an issue, there is probably something structurally deficient with the project.

Comment: "The platform doesn't support some absolutely basic functionality like defining import paths, therefore your code is wrong". Facepalm.