# Can't use absolute paths for import?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Bear with me, I'm not sure if this is purely a React Native issue, or just an ES6 question in general. But I noticed I'm unable to do this:

```
import {navBarRouteMapper} from '/src/helpers';
```

I get an error saying it's unable to resolve the module. I have to do this instead:

```
import {navBarRouteMapper} from '../../../src/helpers';
```

Keeping track of folder depth can get a bit unmanageable as the complexity of the app grows. Why am I not able to use an absolute path?

EDIT:

I see people are recommending adding babel, but I don't want to pollute React Native's system. There's obviously transpilation to ES6 already going on. I was hoping for a solution specific to the React Native ecosystem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing node modules from root directory using es6 and babel-node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068698/importing-node-modules-from-root-directory-using-es6-and-babel-node). React Native uses Babel so I believe your answer lies here.

Comment: You can do this with Browserify.

Comment: do note that the path is a string, and need not be hard-coded in each place it's used. you can use the run time importing too.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with ES6, since module loading is not part of ES6.

Comment: You are missing the module name in your require, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35819147/580167

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a pretty clean solution for React Native, have a look here: https://medium.com/@davidjwoody/how-to-use-absolute-paths-in-react-native-6b06ae3f65d1#.u47sl3p8x.

**TL;DR:**

You'll just have to create a `package.json` file in your `src/helpers` folder:

```
{
   "name": "@helpers" 
}
```

And you will be able to import it from anywhere:

```
import { navBarRouteMapper } from '@helpers'
```

Comment: For images this does not work and it says that it is only supported for debugging purposes

Comment: For images, you just have to write something like:

`import image from '@assets/images.myImage.png'`. Just make sure that you properly export (`default` or not) your variable (image, component, etc).

Comment: so every folder will need a package.json file?